# What are the cheapest laptops available with the following specifications?

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards

I looking for a new laptop with the following requirements:

- Under 2000 Candian dollars
- Touchscreen
- 15.6" screen
- Back-lit keyboard
- i7 series quad core
- Dedicated graphics card
- 1TB of storage
- Win 10

I have found a few laptops that are really close to meeting these requirements but they are always missing one piece or another.

Comment: Your question is a little too broad.  Have you done any shopping on your own yet?  Presenting choices from where you've already done some of the work would narrow things down.  I was involved with a woman in Trois-Rivieres for awhile who had an ASUS gaming laptop she got for around this price, they're a good company, and I know you can get their hardware easily where you are from. Probably a good place to start.

Comment: You're asking for a list.  That isn't the purpose here.